# EditorConfig: How to autofix all files in a project

Tags: editorconfig

Given I have an *.editorconfig* file that dictates consistent indent, line endings, trailing whitespace, etc.

```ini
# http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

As a *developer*, I want to fix all files consistently with a command-line tool that understands *.editorconfig* files. I want to avoid tedious tasks, for instance, manually open and change files.

I imagine if there was a command like for example:

```bash
editorconfix.sh --autofix .
```

Which tools exist for this purpose? What scripts do you use?

Comment: There is an open issue in the `prettier` project to respect .editorconfig: https://github.com/jlongster/prettier/issues/42

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is [eclint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eclint) (and a fork called [editorconfig-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorconfig-tools)). Run

```
eclint check 'src/**/*'
```

to check all files in the `src` directory, or

```
eclint fix 'src/**/*'
```

to fix them. But please note that the tool can produce some surprises when it comes to indentation! The author of the tool [says in a GitHub comment](https://github.com/jedmao/eclint/issues/43#issuecomment-242929632) that he has stopped using the tool himself in favour of language-specific linters:

> To me, EditorConfig is all about – would you believe it – configuring your editor and nothing more. I don't think it should be responsible for linting or fixing, as there are language-specific tools to accomplish those goals (e.g., ESLint for JavaScript). The only way you can reliably lint or fix indentation is to be aware of the language in question and EditorConfig is language agnostic.

Comment: There is no non-npm solution?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy yes there is, check my answer with Gradle, Maven and Ant plugins/tasks ;)

Comment: eclint is not AST-aware, leading to its author dropping it.  It now has security issues in at least one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you use [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) there are tools:

- Gradle: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.ec4j.editorconfig

  To check files:

  ```
  ./gradlew editorconfigCheck
  ```

  To try to fix them automatically:

  ```
  ./gradlew editorconfigFormat
  ```
- Maven: *[EditorConfig Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ec4j.maven/editorconfig-maven-plugin)*. *[editorconfig-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ec4j/editorconfig-maven-plugin)*
- Ant: *[editorconfig-ant-tasks](https://github.com/ec4j/editorconfig-ant-tasks)*